# Reassign a range of values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 5 columns and around 50 rows. Since some of the rows have the same name, I wanted to edit the rows and prefix "age_" to the rows from index 8 to 13. How do I do that?

Right now what I'm doing is to rename it one by one rename it, which is very inconvenient. Is there a easier way to do it?

What I'm doing right now:

```
df2.Tracking_Measure.iloc[8] = 'age_ExposureTarget'
df2.Tracking_Measure.iloc[9] = 'age_ExposureActual'
df2.Tracking_Measure.iloc[10] = 'age_UVTarget'
```

Please do tell me if I'm being unclear! Sorry in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case of **value reassignment**, you can call `iloc` with a list of indices and assign a list to it:

```
to_update = ['x', 'y', 'z']
df2.iloc[[8, 9, 10], df.columns.get_loc('Tracking_Measure')] = to_update
```

---

Given you're trying to **add prefixes** to the columns, you can simplify this to

```
r, c = [8, 9, 10], df.columns.get_loc('Tracking_Measure') 
df2.iloc[r, c] = 'age_' + df2['Tracking_Measure']
```

Or,

```
df2.iloc[r, c] = 'age_' + df2.iloc[r, c]
```

Comment: what about `df2.iloc[[8, 9, 10], df.columns.get_loc('Tracking_Measure')] = 'age_'+ df2.iloc[[8, 9, 10], df.columns.get_loc('Tracking_Measure')]`

Comment: @pyd Didn't see the requirement on adding prefixes. I've edited to add a general answer as well as a more specific one.